# Multisite mapped domain force to use www

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, multisite

I am trying to force domain URL to use www always in WordPress Multisite.

For example if some one type abc.com then it should be redirect automatically to [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com)

I have used the following rules in htaccess but it works only for main domain in WordPress Multisite and not for other sub domains.

```
# Canonical https/www
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

So any help on this, is highly appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: this seems working. Will you please explain what is the difference between my code and your code as it seems same expect the <ifmodule> and thanks again for your help.

Comment: There is an additional ^ after RewriteRule.

Comment: thank you sir for explaination. Will you guide me some documentation for htaccess rules to read. It will be helpful.

Comment: Sure. Always test your redirects in https://htaccess.madewithlove.com. 

Make sure you accept the answer if it is working.

Comment: There is no difference between your rule and the rule posted by OP. The pattern without `^` is same as its without it.